# Change files & photos folders to one storage folder in laravel filemanager

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Inside laravel file manager we have config.lfm file where we have default values:

```
'base_directory' => 'public',

'images_folder_name' => 'storage',//-was photos
'files_folder_name'  => 'storage',//-was files

'shared_folder_name' => '',//-was shares
'thumb_folder_name'  => 'thumbs',
```

When I change this I still get photos and files folders, I can't find where is stored to be those two folder names I look up to all files in `vendor\unisharp\laravel-filemanager\src`....

Any help?

*(Can't find any tags for laravel file manager)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by changing this function `$prefix` and `$base_directory`.

```
public function getPathPrefix($type)
        {
            $default_folder_name = 'storage';
            if ($this->isProcessingImages()) {
                $default_folder_name = 'storage';
            }

            //$prefix = config('lfm.' . $this->currentLfmType() . 's_folder_name', $default_folder_name);
            $prefix = 'storage';
            //$base_directory = config('lfm.base_directory', 'public');
            $base_directory = 'public';
            if ($type === 'dir') {
                $prefix = $base_directory . '/' . $prefix;
            }

            if ($type === 'url' && $base_directory !== 'public') {
                $prefix = config('lfm.url_prefix', config('lfm.prefix', 'laravel-filemanager')) . '/' . $prefix;
            }

            return $prefix;


//return 'storage';
    }
```